# Iex on alchemist, cannot type capital "T"

Tags: elixir, spacemacs, elixir-iex

Just started using spacemacs with Alchemist. I am currently working on an Elixir file with the Filename of times.exs (from Programming Elixir book). The module is named Times.

As I use the Iex on Alchemist, I found out that I cannot type the capital "T" at the start of Iex. Seems like its bound evil-find-char-to-backward, how do i change its binding?

Thank you.

Comment: I voted for “close :: unclear what you're asking” since I was not able to parse neither the problem nor the circumstances it happens under. Please consider investing more time in a good phrasing.

Comment: This was solve by creating a pull request to the devs.